# When calling PHP service from Swift for iOS 9, results don't display

Tags: php, ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and trying to set up an iOS app. At the start of the app I'm dropping a pin on the map and sending the location to my php web service. Then after the next 10 iterations through the map movement, another pin is to be dropped and the location gets sent to the service. Looking at the database everything is getting to the service and is getting loaded to the tables. But, the first time calling the service is the only time that the response data can be retrieved.

Here's the view controller:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Tracker
//
//  Created by Kendall Crouch on 2/6/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 KLC Computing. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    var places = [Dictionary<String, String>()]
    var hasStarted: Bool = false
    var locationCount = 0
    var routeId: NSInteger = -1
    var lastStep: NSInteger = -1
    var markerId: Int = -1
    var manager:CLLocationManager!

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblLatitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblLongitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnStartControl: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnPauseControl: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnStopControl: UIBarButtonItem!

    @IBAction func btnStart(sender: AnyObject) {
        btnStartControl.enabled = false
        btnPauseControl.enabled = true
        btnStopControl.enabled = true
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    @IBAction func btnPause(sender: AnyObject) {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.btnStartControl.enabled = true
        self.btnPauseControl.enabled = false
        hasStarted = false
    }

    @IBAction func btnStop(sender: AnyObject) {
        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.btnStopControl.enabled = false
        self.btnStartControl.enabled = true
        hasStarted = false
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationCount = 500
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locationCount += 1
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        lblLatitude.text = String(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)
        lblLongitude.text = String(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        let latDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        let lonDelta: CLLocationDegrees = 0.05
        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let region: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
        let newCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let newLocation = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate.longitude)
        if locationCount > 10 {
            hasStarted = false
            locationCount = 0
        }
        if !hasStarted {
            hasStarted = true
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in
                var title = "Added on \(NSDate())"
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                }
                else {
                    if let p = placemarks?[0] {
                        let formattedAddressLines = p.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as! NSArray
                        title = formattedAddressLines.componentsJoinedByString(", ")
                    }
                }
                let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = newCoordinate
                annotation.title = title
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                self.places.append(["name":title, "lat":"\(newCoordinate.latitude)", "lon":"\(newCoordinate.longitude)"])
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(self.places, forKey: "places")

                let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://tracker.klccomputing.com/updateRoute.php")!
                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
                let bodyData = "routeId=\(self.routeId)&routeName=\(title)&routeDate=\(NSDate())&lastStep=\(self.lastStep)&latitude=\(newLocation.coordinate.latitude)&longitude=\(newLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
                request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
                let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
                    print(data)
                    if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                        let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode
                        if statusCode == 200 {
                            do {
                                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                                if let jsonData = json {
                                    print("KLCA\(jsonData)")
                                    if let newRouteId: NSInteger = jsonData["routeId"] as? NSInteger {
                                        self.routeId = newRouteId
                                        if let newLastStep: NSInteger = jsonData["lastStep"] as? NSInteger {
                                            self.lastStep = newLastStep
                                            print("KLCB\(self.lastStep)")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch {
                                let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                                print("raw response: \(responseString)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                task.resume()
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Console information. I let the app run 3 iterations. The first time through the variable if statement to get the information from the variable jsonData worked. The second and third times through, they didn't work:

```
Optional(<7b22726f 75746549 64223a31 362c226d 61726b65 72496422 3a36312c 226c6173 74537465 70223a31 7d>)
KLCA{
    lastStep = 1;
    markerId = 61;
    routeId = 16;
}
KLCB1
Optional(<7b22726f 75746549 64223a22 3136222c 226d6172 6b657249 64223a36 322c226c 61737453 74657022 3a327d>)
KLCA{
    lastStep = 2;
    markerId = 62;
    routeId = 16;
}
Optional(<7b22726f 75746549 64223a22 3136222c 226d6172 6b657249 64223a36 332c226c 61737453 74657022 3a327d>)
KLCA{
    lastStep = 2;
    markerId = 63;
    routeId = 16;
}
```

Comment: What about providing some logs showing what happens, along with what should happen?

Comment: Please don't add extended data in comments, where it's highly unreadable. Edit your question to add the additional data, properly formatted.

Comment: I just found something interesting. The first pass the JSON value for "routeId" and "lastStep" are considered numbers by Swift. On the others passes, the "routeId" value is a string while the "lastStep" value is still a number.

Comment: If you log the original data decoded as a string, you'll indeed see that the first one goes `{"routeId":16...` while the next two start with `{"routeId":"16"...`. You can either force the data to be the type you one on the client-side, or ensure the server returns the right kind of data...

Comment: I see what's happening on the server side. Thank you. Now, can you tell me how to decode the data as a string?

Comment: The Objective-C version is `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8Encoding]`. I'll let you convert that to Swift.